# Meaning of と in this sentence from BKB Lesson 9

Tags: particle-と

I'm unsure on what the と in this sentence means:

山田さんと電話で話します。

I'm pretty sure it doesn't mean ''and'' like it usually does so I just wanted to know.

Comment: @A.Ellett Comments are not for answers.

Comment: @snailboat I guess the different groups here have different philosophies about how comments are to be used.  I'll try to keep this in mind for this group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とcan have a number of meanings depending on how it is used.  In this particular context it corresponds with English "to" or "with" as in:

> I will call Mr. Yamada on the phone

or

> I will speak to Mr. Yamada on the phone.

Your impression that  と means "and" is correct.  You could analyze a sentence like

> A  と B  と

as "with A, with B" and perhaps you might see how it is that such a construct is better translated as "A and B".